# URGENT: help recovering lost data

Tags: data-recovery, fstab

I have made a directory: `sudo mkdir /ssd`, the directory was supposed to be mounted to a raid  array called md3. This was done by adding `/dev/md3 /ssd auto defaults 0 0` to fstab. Then after a while where I had used the directory, I realized that I had forgotten to run `sudo mount -a` - and then I did, and now the data is gone. I tried to uncomment the line in fstab and run `sudo mount -a` but that didn't get back my data. What can I do!?

CONTENT OF FSTAB:

```
proc /proc proc defaults 0 0
none /dev/pts devpts gid=5,mode=620 0 0
/dev/md/0 none swap sw 0 0
/dev/md/1 /boot ext3 defaults 0 0
/dev/md/2 / ext4 defaults 0 0
/dev/md3  /ssd  auto   defaults  0 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unmount that filesystem and the files should be right where you left them.

First, type `sudo umount /ssd`, making sure that you are not currently working in that directory, to avoid "Directory in use" errors.

Then move the files in that directory to a safe place.

Finally, remount your filesystem with `sudo mount -a`.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by unmount? Should I run something like: sudo umount /dev/md3 ?

Comment: First, please copy and paste the output of `mount` (without the `-a` switch) so I can see exactly what you're talking about.

Comment: Okay done, see my update :-)

Comment: You probably just mounted a filesystem at the same mount point that your files are in. They were likely just obscured when you mounted the filesystem with `mount -a`.

Comment: Okay, but then what command should I use to get them back? I'm a little afraid of doing something wrong here

Comment: Right - so, just try `sudo umount /ssd` and your files should be there in `/ssd`.

Comment: Then move the files to a safe place and run `sudo mount -a` again to remount the filesystem to `/ssd`.

Comment: Okay cool, When I try to write the command it says: umount: /ssd: device is busy.
        (In some cases useful info about processes that use
         the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1))

Comment: See my edit to the answer. You need to make sure you aren't currently working in that directory, or it can't unmount it. So `cd` somewhere else first.

Comment: Pyhh yes found it - thanks!!!!!! You saved my night!

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6561/discussion-between-platforms-and-niels-kristian)